# Unable to use qapi-gen.py generated files to inject an event

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu, pci-e, mailbox

Tried executing a mailbox command get event records on qemu but output payload length is shown as 20 which is correct according to CXL 2.0. But the content inside the o/p payload is zero. I also tried to generate qapi files using qapi-gen.py file mentioned in the below link
[qapi-code-gen link](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/devel/qapi-code-gen.html)

The above link shows how to generate a specific command. But when I try to run those files I am getting linker error. I am trying to integrate those files into the qemu Makefile but not sure how to do it. Can anyone please help?

I am expecting the get event record output payload to have some values other than zero